# How to get a new table with keys and sum results in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I got a script to count sum for each column in my Google sheet. I'm getting correct result in a Dialog message.
Now I need to make a chart from this data. So I need to extract keys and values and insert to  sheet in active spreadsheet.

```js
function countNutrients(){
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var hA=sh.getRange(2,23,1,sh.getLastColumn()-22).getValues()[0];
  var sum={};
  hA.forEach(function(h,i){sum[h]=0;})
  var vA=sh.getRange(3,23,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()-22).getValues();  
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    r.forEach(function(c,j){
      if(!isNaN(c)) {
        sum[hA[j]]+=c;
       Logger.log(sum);
      }
    });
  }); 
  var html="";
  var keys=Object.keys(sum);
  keys.forEach(function(k,i){
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<br />sum[%s]=%s',k,sum[k]);  
  })
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,'The dish contains');
  

}
```

Any ideas how to get it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Understanding

- You want to retrieve the keys and values from the object of `sum` as an array.
- You want to put the retrieved values to a sheet in the active Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this by modifying your script.

#### Modification point:

- In this answer, the keys and values are retrieved from the object of `sum` using `Object.entries()`.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows. Before you run the script, please set the sheet name that you want to put the values.

##### From:

```
var html="";
var keys=Object.keys(sum);
keys.forEach(function(k,i){
  html+=Utilities.formatString('<br />sum[%s]=%s',k,sum[k]);  
})
var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,'The dish contains');
```

##### To:

```
var values = Object.entries(sum);
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

#### Note:

- In this case, the keys and values are put to the column "A" and "B", respectively. If you want to put the keys and values to other columns, please tell me.
- When you use this modified script, please enable V8 at the script editor.

#### Reference:

- [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: Thank you! It works for me. But I got another problem: all sum results contains dots "." and spreadsheet doesn't recognize it as numbers. How can I change it to comma ","?

Comment: @Timogavk Thank you for replying. About your new question, I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about it. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. About `all sum results contains dots "."`, I think that it is required to confirm the values in the Spreadsheet. So can you post your new issue as new question by including the detail information for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm and think of the issue and solution. Also it will help users think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.